# What kind of clamp is this?

Tags: identification

This clamp is being used on a piece of equipment that is a few years old. I am trying to identify the type of clamp this is.  If you the reader cannot identify it, leave a comment with something similar that will not damage thin wire when clamped.[image: Image of clamp]

Comment: type in test clips into mouser or digikey and browse al the images

Comment: it's a type of aligator clip with smooth jaws. "MUELLER BU-34M" has similar jaws.

Comment: Is this a Kelvin clip?  Because it looks identical to the clips on my cheap Kelvin interface.  Check wither both jaws have continuity.

Comment: @GB-AE7OO Yes they are, thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, they look like the Kelvin clips on my cheap pair, which look identical to this [one](https://ast-labs.com/shop/test_cables/kelvin-clip-5-pin-din-plug-lcr-meter-test-probe-2-ft/). 
[image]
 Please note the insulated hinge found on both.
Here is a set of clips from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B019RFO3II) and one from [Ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/LCR-Meter-Test-Leads-Lead-Clip-Cable-Terminal-Kelvin-Probe-Wires-w-4-BNC/251680384557?_trkparms=aid%3D555018%26algo%3DPL.SIM%26ao%3D2%26asc%3D20160908110712%26meid%3D6a776b2211474433830bce2956a58878%26pid%3D100677%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D30%26mehot%3Dpp%26sd%3D111152585041%26itm%3D251680384557%26pmt%3D1%26noa%3D0%26pg%3D2386202&_trksid=p2386202.c100677.m4598).
If so then you need to replace it with another Kelvin clip, like one of the following:
[Found at Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MC29RDU)
[Found at Ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/2pcs-1-pair-3-6-inch-Kelvin-Probe-Test-Clip-for-LCR-cable/251637969513?_trkparms=aid%3D1110002%26algo%3DSPLICE.SOI%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20190711095549%26meid%3D6b8165f390ca47ddafc815e464e5cef0%26pid%3D100047%26rk%3D5%26rkt%3D12%26mehot%3Des%26sd%3D251680384557%26itm%3D251637969513%26pmt%3D1%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D2047675&_trksid=p2047675.c100047.m2108)
[AST Labs](https://ast-labs.com/shop/test_clips/large-kelvin-clip-fine-tip-gold-plated-lcr-meter/)
That is just a small selection.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the links you provided.

Answer (score 6):

It is identical to a Kelvin clip pair that I have. Mine have two coaxial cables and two BNC connectors per clip (so four in total for the red + black clips).

[image]

If you don't need the Kelvin feature (independent connections to each side of the jaws) there are plenty of small alligator clips.

Comment: Thank you for your help